# How to take one character at a time as input from a string of characters without space in c?

Tags: c, string

Suppose,"5181 2710 9900 0012"- is a string of digits.I need to take one single digit at a time as input from the string of number without space to make arithmatic operations . So, i write that,

```
int a[20];
for(int i=0;i<16;i++)
{
scanf("%d",&a[i]);
  }
```

but it didn't give me expected result. But when i use "%1d"instead of "%d",it gave me the  expected result. so, how it works?

Comment: isn't the s in scanf supposed to be lowercase?

Comment: See [scanf reference](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/scanf)

Comment: yeah other than that, like what @Gerard van Helden said, use %1d to be sure. Also, if your using gcc, make sure to use gcc -Wall -o yourprogram yourprogram.c to check if your program compiles correctly. I compiled your code and it gave me an error because scanf wasn't lowercase, just little things like that.

Comment: In your code?  Nothing, it won't compile, as commented by @RoadRunner.

Comment: Sorry, i made mistake in writing s of scanf function in uppercase letter. But it was not the problem at all. The problem was the uses of "%d" and "%1d" in my code gave me different output according to my problem statement.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

<s>Since scanf is the inverse of printf, you could verify this by printing any number with the modifier (just a little tip).</s>*

In general, the number before the format is a 'width' modifier. In this case it means you're only reading one byte into a number. If you specify %d, it may be a number of arbitrary length.

Example:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    int a;
    sscanf("1234", "%d", &a);
    printf("%d\n", a); // prints 1234
    sscanf("1234", "%1d", &a); 
    printf("%d\n"m a); // prints 1
}
```

---

*) this appears to be false for this particular case. Makes sense that numbers are not truncated when specifiying a `%d` format, though, since that would change the meaning of the number. However, for many cases you could try what `printf` would do to predict `scanf`'s behavior. But of course, reading the manual or docs on it is always the more helpful approach :)

Comment: Sorry, i could not understand your comment fully. Would you please explain me in details?

Comment: scanf is not really the inverse of printf, there are a lot of differences